# Differential equations solving

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The number of organisms in a population at time t is denoted by x. Treating x as a continuous variable, the differential equation satisfied by x and t is $$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac {xe^{-t}}{k + e^{-t}}$$

where k is  a positive constant.

$i)$ Given that x = 10 when t = 0, solve the differential equation, obtaining a relation between x, k and t.

I'm mainly stuck in getting the $x$ to one side and $t$ on another, if you could help me there I think I can do the rest of the question.

Comment: To separate them, all you have to do is divide both sides by $x$ and integrate both sides with respect to $t$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{e^{-t}}{k+e^{-t}}\,dt$$

Now integrate both sides and apply the initial condition.

Comment: Thank you, I got to $ln|x| = \int \frac {1} {-u - k}$ where $u =  e^{-t}$, what do I do now?

Comment: Not quite.  We have $\log(x(t))=-\int \frac{1}{k+u}\,du=A-\log(k+e^{-t})$.  Now, use $x(0)=10=A-\log(k+1)$ and solve for $A$.

Comment: Why is it $(x(t))$? I got to $ln(10) = A - ln(k + 1)$ how do I solve for A when k is another unknown?

Comment: It is $x(t)$ since $x$ is a function of $t$, is it not?  And if $k$ is an unknown, you will need additional information to find it.  For example, what happens to the population as $t\to \infty$?  That is $x_\infty=A+\log(k)$.  So, if you know $x_\infty$, for example, then you can see that $k=e^{x_\infty-A}$ (or $A=x_\infty -\log(k)$) and $x(10)=A+\log(k+1)$.  But you are only asked to find a relationship between $x$, $t$, and $k$.  So, just eliminate $A$ as $A=10+\log(k+1)$.

Comment: You should get after exponentiation on both sides simultaneously $x(t)=\dfrac{B}{k+e^{-t}}$, $B=\pm e^A$, where then $B=10(k+1)$, $x(t)=10\dfrac{k+1}{k+e^{-t}}$.